# C# Best way to expose a method while maintaining a private list

Tags: c#, list, private

I'm essentially trying to pull back a custom class from a list of objects without exposing my list.  Below is how I got it to work but I don't think this is the most elegant way.  Also - how do I call an instance of this call without instantiating a new class?  I'd like to do everything in one line.

I'd like to be able to call my Request in one line

```
Library.ConnectionController cc = new Library.ConnectionController();
cc = cc.Request("z");
```

And here is my class

```
class Library
{
    public ConnectionController Retrieve_Controller_By_Domain(string Domain)
    {
        ConnectionController cc = new ConnectionController();
        cc = cc.Request(Domain);
        return cc;
    }

    internal class ConnectionController
    {
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }
        public string ProjectName { get; set; }
        public string Domain { get; set; }
        public string SQLServer { get; set; }
        public string SQLDatabase { get; set; }

        public ConnectionController Request(string Domain)
        {
            InternalLibrary il = new InternalLibrary();
            ConnectionController Requested = il.ccList.Where(m => m.Domain.ToUpper() == Domain.ToUpper())
                .Select(m => new ConnectionController
                {
                    UserName = m.UserName,
                    Password = m.Password,
                    ProjectName = m.ProjectName,
                    Domain = m.Domain,
                    SQLServer = m.SQLServer,
                    SQLDatabase = m.SQLDatabase
                }).ToList()[0];

            return Requested;
        }
    }

    private class InternalLibrary
    {
        public List<ConnectionController> ccList
        {
            get
            {
                return (new List<ConnectionController> { 
                    new ConnectionController() { 
                        UserName = "x", 
                        Password="y",
                        ProjectName="r",
                        Domain = "z", 
                        SQLDatabase = "a", 
                        SQLServer = "b"
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a version of your code written in a simpler way

```
namespace Library
{
public class ConnectionController
{
    private static readonly List<ConnectionController> CcList = new List<ConnectionController>
    {
        new ConnectionController
        {
            UserName = "x",
            Password = "y",
            ProjectName = "r",
            Domain = "z",
            SQLDatabase = "a",
            SQLServer = "b"
        }
    };

    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public string ProjectName { get; set; }
    public string Domain { get; set; }
    public string SQLServer { get; set; }
    public string SQLDatabase { get; set; }

    public static ConnectionController Request(string domain)
    {
        return CcList.Where(m => m.Domain.ToUpper() == domain.ToUpper())
            .Select(m => new ConnectionController
            {
                UserName = m.UserName,
                Password = m.Password,
                ProjectName = m.ProjectName,
                Domain = m.Domain,
                SQLServer = m.SQLServer,
                SQLDatabase = m.SQLDatabase
            }).ToList()[0];
    }
}
}
```

then you could

```
var requesteed =  ConnectionController.Request("x");
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understand exactly what you want. But here is corrected version using some basic ideas:

1. Using `static` method to retrieve `controller`. Since there could be no `controller` with requested name found we need to call some external request function. So the best way is to make it `static` function of the `returned type`.
2. Using static `list` in InternalLibrary so it will be created (or evaluated) only once.
3. Using `FirstOrDefault()` `LINQ` extension method since there could be empty result.

Here is the code:

```
public class Library
{
    public class ConnectionController
    {
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }
        public string ProjectName { get; set; }
        public string Domain { get; set; }
        public string SQLServer { get; set; }
        public string SQLDatabase { get; set; }

        public static ConnectionController Request(string Domain)
        {
            return InternalLibrary.ccList.
                Where(m => m.Domain.Equals(Domain, 
                           StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)).
                FirstOrDefault();
        }
    }

    private class InternalLibrary
    {
        public static readonly List<ConnectionController> ccList =
            new List<ConnectionController>
            { 
                new ConnectionController()
                { 
                    UserName = "x", 
                    Password="y",
                    ProjectName="r",
                    Domain = "z", 
                    SQLDatabase = "a", 
                    SQLServer = "b"
                }
            };
    }
}
```

And you can use this like this (note that `controller` could be `null`)

```
var controller = Library.ConnectionController.Request("z");
```

P.S. I didn't remove the `InternalLibrary` class assuming that this is not just a hard coded list but complex class with some separated logics.